# Versão de teste e versão de produção Android

Tags: android, xamarin-forms

Estou com a seguinte dúvida sobre gerenciamento de aplicativos Android.

Quando vamos publicar uma versão na **Google PlayStore (Android)**, temos 3 opções de escolha, sendo elas **Alfa, Beta e Produção.**

Publiquei meu aplicativo na versão Alfa e adicionei alguns Testadores da versão, ou seja, quem está cadastrado nessa versão como Testador poderá baixar o aplicativo de homologação.

A versão foi testada, aprovada e enviada para produção, porém os usuários que estão configurados como *Testers* não conseguem baixar a versão de produção.

> **Imagem das opções de publicação:**
>
> [image: Imagem das opções de publicação:]
>
> **Testadores das versão de homologação:**
>
> [image: Testadores das versão de homologação]

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de fazer com que os *Testers* baixem a versão de produção.

Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Edite os testadores e os remova-os, devido estarem como testadores eles só vão receber a versão Alfa onde foram adicionados e consequentemente não irão conseguir receber a atualização da versão de produção... [Aqui](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/search?q=alfa&from_promoted_search=true) você pode ler mais...